# Hide IIS from network

Tags: iis

I installed iis on Windows to host a test website, but it's shared to everyone on the network. Is there a way to disable this so it is not shared to any other computers?

Comment: What is shared? The PC? IIS? The network?

Comment: The web server is visible from anywhere on the network.

Comment: There are several options. The easiest is that you edit the IIS bindings to only listen on localhost.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best option would be to go into windows firewall

If it is disabled, enable it:

Find all inbound rules on local port 80 and disable them.

Set your bindings in iis to websitename:80

Open your hosts file and and local-ipaddress websitename

That should do it.

To test this from any other pc run:

```
netstat local-ipaddress 80
```